# Haskell concurrency and Handles

Tags: haskell, concurrency, handle

I'm writing a little notification server to push data to a client. The basic architecture looks something like this (pared down pseudo-code):

```
acceptConnections sock = forever $ do
    connection <- accept sock
    forkIO (handleConnection connection)

handleConnection connection = do
    connectionHandle <- socketToHandle connection ReadWriteMode
    handleMessage connectionHandle
    hClose connectionHandle

handleMessage connectionHandle = forever $ do
    message <- hGetLine connectionHandle 
    if shouldPushMessage message
        then hPutStrLn targetConnection message
        else return ()
```

Where targetConnection (in handleMessage) is from a separate connection and is hanging up handleMessage in a different thread waiting for its buffer to be filled. I would think this would cause a problem as I have 2 threads accessing the same Handle. So, my question is, why isn't this a problem? Or is it, and I just haven't seen it turn into an issue yet? In my actual application, when I grab targetConnection, I do so through a map I access via an MVar, but it's not being safely accessed at the hGetLine call.

Disclaimer: I'm a complete Haskell and multi-threaded newb

Thanks for any explanations/insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Handle`, as [implemented in GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/src/GHC-IO-Handle-Types.html#Handle), is already an MVar wrapping over the underlying [IODevice](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-IO-Device.html#t%3aIODevice).  I didn't quite get what you're doing (not saying it was unclear, I'm a little ill so perhaps I'm slow) but am guessing GHCs built in thread-safe handling of `Handle` is saving you.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm sure I didn't do the best job illustrating what I was doing--basically I was curious how hPutStrLn and hGetLine could be called "simultaneously" by different threads on the same Handle. You answered my clumsy question. Thanks!