# Why is chat server example on haskell.org thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, io, thread-safety

I'm new to Haskell and I can't figure out what I'm not understanding about this example on the Haskell wiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Implement_a_chat_server

The specific code in question is this:

```
runConn :: (Socket, SockAddr) -> Chan Msg -> -> IO ()
runConn (sock, _) chan = do
    let broadcast msg = writeChan chan msg
    hdl <- socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
    hSetBuffering hdl NoBuffering
    chan' <- dupChan chan
    -- fork off thread for reading from the duplicated channel
    forkIO $ fix $ \loop -> do
        line <- readChan chan'
        hPutStrLn hdl line
        loop
    -- read lines from socket and echo them back to the user
    fix $ \loop -> do
        line <- liftM init (hGetLine hdl) 
        broadcast line
        loop
```

The code above has one thread writing to the handle `hdl` at the same time (potentially) as another thread is reading from it. Is this safe?

I suspect the nature of `forkIO` (being internal to Haskell and not a system thread library or process) is what makes this work, but I'm not sure.

I checked the documentation of [forkIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html) for any mention of IO handles
but found nothing. I also checked the documentation of [System.IO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/System-IO.html) but couldn't find any mention of using handles between threads without using locking.

So can someone tell me how I should know when something like this is safe when the docs don't mention anything about thread safety?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell concurrency and Handles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136375/haskell-concurrency-and-handles)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly what sort of badness the `MVar`s in the implementation of `Handle` are preventing, but you can assume everything in haskell is "thread safe" in the sense of "this won't blow up if I use it in concurrent code". A variation on the above code that we might call not "thread safe" in the haskelly sense might be if you had `forkIO`-ed *two* threads which both received from the chan and echoed it back; in that case the characters could be *interleaved*, e.g. "hellhelo lo worldworld"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the nature of `forkIO` that makes this works but the nature of `MVar` that is used to implement both `Chan` and `Handle`.

If you want to understand how `Chan` works take a look at this section ["MVar as building blocks: Unbounded Channels"](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_channels) in chapter 7 of the excellent book ["Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026365.do) by Simon Marlow. In the same chapter there is a section about [`forkIO`](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html) and [`MVar`](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_mvars) that will help you understand how `Handle` can be implemented in a thread safe way.

[Chapter 12](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch12.html) talks specifically about various ways to implement network servers, including a chat server that is implemented using STM instead of `Chan`s.

Comment: Thanks for useful references. Should I assume all the (non-pure) APIs in the 'base' package are safe to access concurrently? or should I get in the habit of checking the source for use of `MVar`s?

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't safe, blocking sockets would be almost impossible to use. If your protocol is asynchronous and you're using blocking sockets, you need a thread blocking on read pretty much all the time. If you then needed to send a message to the other side, how could you do it? Wait for the other side to send you a message?